# Is it possible to express "t" variable from Cubic Bezier Curve equation?

Tags: algorithm, math, glsl, cubic-bezier

I want draw bezier curve only by fragment shader to connect nodes in my editor. I know all 4 points that define Bezier Curve. And Fragment Shader is called for every pixel, so i can just check:  if "t" for gl_Coord.x is between 0 and 1 then set frag_color to Red for example. I want to avoid loops in shader that's inefficient. Best way, i think, is check for points that lay on the curve. But how to do it for Bezier Curves?

Is it possible to express "t" variable from cubic bezier equation?

```
x = ((1-t)^3 * p0.x) + (3 * (1-t)^2 * t * p1.x) + (3 * (1 - t) * t^2 * p2.x) + (t^3 * p3.x);

t = ?
```

Website Wolfram Aplha give me that formula(in GetBezierT function). But formula give me wrong "t" values and i have half of parabola instead of curve:

```c
#version 150
.....
layout (origin_upper_left, pixel_center_integer) in vec4 gl_FragCoord;
out vec4 frag_color;
.....
vec4 BackgroundColor = vec4(0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 1.0);
vec2 p0 = vec2(61.0f,87.0f);
vec2 p1 = vec2(181.0f, 39.0f);
vec2 p2 = vec2(283.0f, 178.0f);
vec2 p3 = vec2(416.0f, 132.0f);

float getBezierT(float x, float a, float b, float c, float d)
{
      return  float(sqrt(3) * 
          sqrt(-4 * b * d + 4 * b * x + 3 * c * c + 2 * c * d - 8 * c * x - d * d + 4 * d * x) 
            + 6 * b - 9 * c + 3 * d) 
            / (6 * (b - 2 * c + d));
}

void main() {  
    .....
    frag_color = BackgroundColor; 
    .....
    float tx = getBezierT(gl_FragCoord.x, p0.x, p1.x, p2.x, p3.x);
    float ty = getBezierT(gl_FragCoord.y, p0.y, p1.y, p2.y, p3.y);

    if (tx >= 0.0f && tx <= 1.0f && ty >= 0.0f && ty <= 1.0f)
    {
        if(abs(tx-ty) <  0.01f) // simple check is that one point with little bias
        frag_color = vec4(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Made a mistake. I thought there was no point in looking for `t`. I thought I would put up with it. But after the answer given by `Salix alba` and `Stratubas`, I realized that if `tX` is equal to `tY`, this means that this point will lie on the curve, because in the formula for each point one value of `t` is substituted for both `x` and `y`. Maybe there are cases when different `tX` and `tY` can also give a point on this curve, but we can just ignore that. The algorithm for constructing a bezier curve implies that we linearly increase `t` and substitute it into the formula and it does not matter how much the curve is twisted, the algorithm returns the coordinates of each next point sequentially along the curve.

Therefore, first of all, I again open this question: how to express the variable t from a cubic bezier equation?

Tried to express t, but it is insanely difficult for me. It is necessary to evaluate the effectiveness of this approach for "scientific purposes" =). Before asking a question here, I searched a lot, but never found that someone would try to use this method. I need to understand why.

**UPDATE 2**

You have done an excellent job! I did not expect to receive such detailed answers. Exactly what i needed. Give me time to check everything=)

**UPDATE 3**

Conclusions: Accurate expression of `t` from the Cubic Bezier equation. Time-consuming task, but approximate values don't have practical use. To solve this problem, it is necessary to analyze the equation data, find patterns and develop new formula for constructing bezier curves. With a new relations of variables among themselves, then it will become possible to express `t` in a different way. If we represent the Cubic Bezier formula in the form of the sum of the products of the `x` coordinates of the control points by four coefficients ( `v0` -`v3`) generated by the functions in the four parts of the equation depending on the value of `t`. This gives the formula x = a.x * v0 + b.x * v1 + c.x * v2 + d.x * v3. And if you look at the table below, you can get the idea that the expression for the variable `t` is an equation with four unknowns. Because both the values and the relations of some of the `V` coefficients between themselves change in an unpredictable way from iteration to iteration. Finding that new abstract formula is beyond the scope of this question and my competence.

[image: Table of V0-V3 Coefficients]

Many thanks to all for your work, especially `Spektre` for the unique development and efforts made to optimize the rendering algorithm. Your approach is the best choice for me=)

Comment: I think that drawing a Bezier curve only in fragment shader is inefficient. You will have to calculate a lot a stuff for pixels that are not actually part of the curve, and the calculations are not trivial. I would suggest to simply subdivide the curve into a series of lines, and then draw the lines. The code will be simpler and more efficient.

Comment: see [Draw Quadratic Curve on GPU](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31423105/2521214)... instead of computing `t` you need to find perpendicular distance to curve ... it might be done by approximation or bisection search but you will not avoid `for` loop ...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you need is to search your cubic path and remember closest point. This can be done recursively with increasing precisions here small **C++ GL** example:

```cpp
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
double pnt[]=                   // cubic curve control points
    {
    -0.9,-0.8,0.0,
    -0.6,+0.8,0.0,
    +0.6,+0.8,0.0,
    +0.9,-0.8,0.0,
    };
const int pnts3=sizeof(pnt)/sizeof(pnt[0]);
const int pnts=pnts3/3;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
double cubic_a[4][3];           // cubic coefficients
void cubic_init(double *pnt)    // compute cubic coefficients
    {
    int i;
    double *p0=pnt,*p1=p0+3,*p2=p1+3,*p3=p2+3;
    for (i=0;i<3;i++)           // cubic BEZIER coefficients
        {
        cubic_a[0][i]=                                    (    p0[i]);
        cubic_a[1][i]=                        (3.0*p1[i])-(3.0*p0[i]);
        cubic_a[2][i]=            (3.0*p2[i])-(6.0*p1[i])+(3.0*p0[i]);
        cubic_a[3][i]=(    p3[i])-(3.0*p2[i])+(3.0*p1[i])-(    p0[i]);
        }
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
double* cubic(double t)         // return point on cubic from parameter
    {
    int i;
    static double p[3];
    double tt=t*t,ttt=tt*t;
    for (i=0;i<3;i++)
     p[i]=cubic_a[0][i]
        +(cubic_a[1][i]*t)
        +(cubic_a[2][i]*tt)
        +(cubic_a[3][i]*ttt);
    return p;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
double cubic_d(double *p)       // return closest distance from point to cubic
    {
    int i,j;
    double t,tt,t0,t1,dt,
           l,ll,a,*q;
    tt=-1.0; ll=-1.0; t0=0.0; t1=1.001; dt=0.05;
    for (j=0;j<3;j++)
        {
        for (t=t0;t<=t1;t+=dt)
            {
            q=cubic(t);
            for (l=0.0,i=0;i<3;i++) l+=(p[i]-q[i])*(p[i]-q[i]);
            if ((ll<0.0)||(ll>l)){ ll=l; tt=t; }
            }
        t0=tt-dt; if (t0<0.0) t0=0.0;
        t1=tt+dt; if (t1>1.0) t1=1.0;
        dt*=0.2;
        }
    return sqrt(ll);
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void gl_draw()
    {
    int i;
    double t,p[3],dp;
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);

    // GL render
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

                    glColor3f(0.2,0.2,0.2); glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP); for (i=0;i<pnts3;i+=3) glVertex3dv(pnt+i); glEnd();
    glPointSize(5); glColor3f(0.0,0.0,0.7); glBegin(GL_POINTS); for (i=0;i<pnts3;i+=3) glVertex3dv(pnt+i); glEnd(); glPointSize(1);
    cubic_init(pnt);glColor3f(0.2,0.7,0.7); glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP); for (t=0.0;t<1.001;t+=0.025) glVertex3dv(cubic(t)); glEnd();

    glColor3f(0.0,0.7,0.0); glBegin(GL_POINTS);
    p[2]=0.0; dp=0.01;
    for (p[0]=-1.0;p[0]<1.001;p[0]+=dp)
     for (p[1]=-1.0;p[1]<1.001;p[1]+=dp)
      if (cubic_d(p)<0.05)
       glVertex3dv(p);
    glEnd();

    glFlush();
    SwapBuffers(hdc);
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

so first you call `cubic_init` once to compute the coefficients and then to obtain point on curve as function of parameter use:

```
double pnt[3] = cubic(double t);
```

Now the reverse (I return closest distance `ll` but you can easily change it to return the `tt`)

```
double dist = cubic_d(double pnt[3]);
```

Now you just port this to shader and determine if fragment is close enough to curve to render it (hence the distance instead of `t` also for speed you can get rid of the last `sqrt` and use powered values latter).

The `gl_draw` function renders control points(blue) / lines(gray) the bezier curve (aqua) with GL and then emulates fragment shader to render curve with thickness `2*0.05` in (green)...

Preview:

[image: preview]

Now its just a matter of porting that into GLSL. In order to use GLSL native way of passing vertexes you need to enlarge the area a bit like in here:

- [Draw Quadratic Curve on GPU](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31423105/2521214)

But you need to change the geometry a bit to account for 4 control points instead of just 3. That stuff should be in geometry shader ...

So in geometry shader you should do the cubic_init, and in fragment shader `discard` if distance `cubic_d` is bigger than thickness.

The search is based on:

- [How approximation search works](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36163847/2521214)

which I develop for problems like this. The search loop itself can be tweaked a bit to improve performance/precision ... but beware the initial search should sample the curve to at least 4-5 chunks otherwise it might stop working properly for some shapes.

**[Edit1] after some thinking here the GLSL version**

**Vertex**

```cpp
// Vertex
#version 400 core
layout(location = 0) in vec2 pos;   // control points (QUADS)
layout(location = 3) in vec3 col;   // color

out vec2 vpos;
out vec3 vcol;

void main()
    {
    vpos=pos;
    vcol=col;
    gl_Position=vec4(pos,0.0,1.0);
    }
```

**Geometry:**

```cpp
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Geometry
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#version 400 core
layout(lines_adjacency) in;
layout(triangle_strip, max_vertices = 4) out;

uniform float d=0.05;   // half thickness

in vec2 vpos[];
in vec3 vcol[];

out vec2 a0,a1,a2,a3;   // cubic coefficients
out vec3 fcol;          // color
out vec2 fpos;          // position
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void main()
    {
    vec4 p0,p1,p2,p3,a,b;
    p0=gl_in[0].gl_Position;
    p1=gl_in[1].gl_Position;
    p2=gl_in[2].gl_Position;
    p3=gl_in[3].gl_Position;
    // compute BEZIER coefficients
    a0.x=                             (    p0.x);
    a1.x=                  (3.0*p1.x)-(3.0*p0.x);
    a2.x=       (3.0*p2.x)-(6.0*p1.x)+(3.0*p0.x);
    a3.x=(p3.x)-(3.0*p2.x)+(3.0*p1.x)-(    p0.x);
    a0.y=                             (    p0.y);
    a1.y=                  (3.0*p1.y)-(3.0*p0.y);
    a2.y=       (3.0*p2.y)-(6.0*p1.y)+(3.0*p0.y);
    a3.y=(p3.y)-(3.0*p2.y)+(3.0*p1.y)-(    p0.y);
    // compute BBOX
    a=p0;                     b=p0;
    if (a.x > p1.x) a.x=p1.x; if (b.x < p1.x) b.x=p1.x;
    if (a.x > p2.x) a.x=p2.x; if (b.x < p2.x) b.x=p2.x;
    if (a.x > p3.x) a.x=p3.x; if (b.x < p3.x) b.x=p3.x;
    if (a.y > p1.y) a.y=p1.y; if (b.y < p1.y) b.y=p1.y;
    if (a.y > p2.y) a.y=p2.y; if (b.y < p2.y) b.y=p2.y;
    if (a.y > p3.y) a.y=p3.y; if (b.y < p3.y) b.y=p3.y;
    // enlarge by d
    a.x-=d; a.y-=d;
    b.x+=d; b.y+=d;
    // pass it as QUAD
    fcol=vcol[0];
    fpos=vec2(a.x,a.y); gl_Position=vec4(a.x,a.y,0.0,1.0); EmitVertex();
    fpos=vec2(a.x,b.y); gl_Position=vec4(a.x,b.y,0.0,1.0); EmitVertex();
    fpos=vec2(b.x,a.y); gl_Position=vec4(b.x,a.y,0.0,1.0); EmitVertex();
    fpos=vec2(b.x,b.y); gl_Position=vec4(b.x,b.y,0.0,1.0); EmitVertex();
    EndPrimitive();
    }

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Fragment:**

```cpp
// Fragment
#version 400 core
uniform float d=0.05;   // half thickness

in vec2 fpos;           // fragment position
in vec3 fcol;           // fragment color
in vec2 a0,a1,a2,a3;    // cubic coefficients

out vec4 col;

vec2 cubic(float t)     // return point on cubic from parameter
    {
    float tt=t*t,ttt=tt*t;
    return a0+(a1*t)+(a2*tt)+(a3*ttt);
    }

void main()
    {
    vec2 p;
    int i;
    float t,tt,t0,t1,dt,l,ll;
    tt=-1.0; ll=-1.0; dt=0.05; t0=0.0; t1=1.0; l=0.0;
    for (i=0;i<3;i++)
        {
        for (t=t0;t<=t1;t+=dt)
            {
            p=cubic(t)-fpos;
            l=length(p);
            if ((ll<0.0)||(ll>l)){ ll=l; tt=t; }
            }
        t0=tt-dt; if (t0<0.0) t0=0.0;
        t1=tt+dt; if (t1>1.0) t1=1.0;
        dt*=0.2;
        }
    if (ll>d) discard;
    col=vec4(fcol,1.0); // ll,tt can be used for coloring or texturing
    }
```

It expect 4 BEZIER control points per CUBIC in form of `GL_LINES_ADJACENCY` since `GL_QUADS` are no more :( When I use it like this (inside gl_draw):

```cpp
glUseProgram(prog_id);               // use our shaders
i=glGetUniformLocation(prog_id,"d"); // set line half thickness
glUniform1f(i,0.02);
glColor3f(0.2,0.7,0.2);              // color
glBegin(GL_LINES_ADJACENCY); 
for (i=0;i<pnts3;i+=3)
 glVertex3dv(pnt+i);
glEnd();
glUseProgram(0);
```

The result looks like this:

[image: shader preview]

and of coarse is **a lot of faster** than the old api dotted shader emulation :). I know old api and new style GLSL shaders should not be mixed so you should create **VAO/VBO** instead of using `glBegin/glEnd`... I am too lazy to do that just for the purpose of this answer ...

**Here the non function (more y per single x) example (compared with the CPU side dots)**:

```cpp
double pnt[]=                   // cubic curve control points
    {
    +0.9,-0.8,0.0,
    -2.5,+0.8,0.0,
    +2.5,+0.8,0.0,
    -0.9,-0.8,0.0,
    };
```

[image: non function]

As you can see both approaches matches the shape (dots used bigger thickness). In order this to work the search coefficients (`dt`) must be set properly to not miss a solution...

PS solving the cubic your way leads to 2 set of these:

[image: analytical solution]

Which I strongly doubt can be much computed faster than simple search.

**[Edit2] further improvements**

I simply changed the geometry shader so that it sample the curve into 10 segments and emit BBOX for each separatelly eliminating a lot of empty space that needed to be processed before. I changed the color layout and rendering order a bit.

This is new result (identical to previous one but several times faster due lower empty space ratio):

[image: preview]

This is how the coverage looks now:

[image: coverage]

Before the coverage was BBOX of control points + enlargement by `d` which in this case was much bigger then curve itself (2 control points are outside view).

**Here updated Geometry shader**:

```cpp
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Geometry
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#version 400 core
layout(lines_adjacency) in;
layout(triangle_strip, max_vertices = 40) out;  // 4*n <= 60

uniform float d=0.05;   // half thickness

in vec2 vpos[];
in vec3 vcol[];

out vec2 a0,a1,a2,a3;   // cubic coefficients
out vec3 fcol;          // color
out vec2 fpos;          // position
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
vec2 cubic(float t)     // return point on cubic from parameter
    {
    float tt=t*t,ttt=tt*t;
    return a0+(a1*t)+(a2*tt)+(a3*ttt);
    }
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void main()
    {
    float t,dt=1.0/10.0;    // 1/n
    vec2 p0,p1,p2,p3,a,b;
    p0=gl_in[0].gl_Position.xy;
    p1=gl_in[1].gl_Position.xy;
    p2=gl_in[2].gl_Position.xy;
    p3=gl_in[3].gl_Position.xy;
    // compute BEZIER coefficients
    a0.x=                             (    p0.x);
    a1.x=                  (3.0*p1.x)-(3.0*p0.x);
    a2.x=       (3.0*p2.x)-(6.0*p1.x)+(3.0*p0.x);
    a3.x=(p3.x)-(3.0*p2.x)+(3.0*p1.x)-(    p0.x);
    a0.y=                             (    p0.y);
    a1.y=                  (3.0*p1.y)-(3.0*p0.y);
    a2.y=       (3.0*p2.y)-(6.0*p1.y)+(3.0*p0.y);
    a3.y=(p3.y)-(3.0*p2.y)+(3.0*p1.y)-(    p0.y);
    p1=cubic(0.0);
    for (t=dt;t < 1.001;t+=dt)
        {
        p0=p1; p1=cubic(t);
        // compute BBOX
        a=p0;                     b=p0;
        if (a.x > p1.x) a.x=p1.x; if (b.x < p1.x) b.x=p1.x;
        if (a.y > p1.y) a.y=p1.y; if (b.y < p1.y) b.y=p1.y;
        // enlarge by d
        a.x-=d; a.y-=d;
        b.x+=d; b.y+=d;
        // pass it as QUAD
        fcol=vcol[0];
        fpos=vec2(a.x,a.y); gl_Position=vec4(a.x,a.y,0.0,1.0); EmitVertex();
        fpos=vec2(a.x,b.y); gl_Position=vec4(a.x,b.y,0.0,1.0); EmitVertex();
        fpos=vec2(b.x,a.y); gl_Position=vec4(b.x,a.y,0.0,1.0); EmitVertex();
        fpos=vec2(b.x,b.y); gl_Position=vec4(b.x,b.y,0.0,1.0); EmitVertex();
        EndPrimitive();
        }
    }
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

My gfx card has 60 vertex limit so as I output triangle strips emulating QUADs the limit on segments is `60/4 = 15` I used `n=10` just to be sure it runs on lower HW. In order to change the number of segments see the 2 lines with comment containing `n`

**[Edit3] even better coverage useful/empty space ratio**

I changed the AABB BBOX coverage to ~OOB BBOX without overlaps. This also allows to pass actual range of `t` into fragment speeding up the search ~10 times. Updated shaders:

**Vertex:**

```
// Vertex
#version 400 core
layout(location = 0) in vec2 pos;   // control points (QUADS)
layout(location = 3) in vec3 col;   // color

out vec2 vpos;
out vec3 vcol;

void main()
    {
    vpos=pos;
    vcol=col;
    gl_Position=vec4(pos,0.0,1.0);
    }
```

**Geometry:**

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Geometry
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#version 400 core
layout(lines_adjacency) in;
layout(triangle_strip, max_vertices = 40) out;  // 4*n <= 60

uniform float d=0.05;   // half thickness

in vec2 vpos[];
in vec3 vcol[];

out vec2 a0,a1,a2,a3;   // cubic coefficients
out vec3 fcol;          // color
out vec2 fpos;          // position
out vec2 trange;        // t range of chunk
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
vec2 cubic(float t)     // return point on cubic from parameter
    {
    float tt=t*t,ttt=tt*t;
    return a0+(a1*t)+(a2*tt)+(a3*ttt);
    }
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void main()
    {
    int i,j,n=10,m=10;              // n,m
    float t,dd,d0,d1,dt=1.0/10.0;   // 1/n
    float tt,dtt=1.0/100.0;         // 1/(n*m)
    vec2 p0,p1,p2,p3,u,v;
    vec2 q0,q1,q2,q3;
    p0=gl_in[0].gl_Position.xy;
    p1=gl_in[1].gl_Position.xy;
    p2=gl_in[2].gl_Position.xy;
    p3=gl_in[3].gl_Position.xy;
    // compute BEZIER coefficients
    a0.x=                             (    p0.x);
    a1.x=                  (3.0*p1.x)-(3.0*p0.x);
    a2.x=       (3.0*p2.x)-(6.0*p1.x)+(3.0*p0.x);
    a3.x=(p3.x)-(3.0*p2.x)+(3.0*p1.x)-(    p0.x);
    a0.y=                             (    p0.y);
    a1.y=                  (3.0*p1.y)-(3.0*p0.y);
    a2.y=       (3.0*p2.y)-(6.0*p1.y)+(3.0*p0.y);
    a3.y=(p3.y)-(3.0*p2.y)+(3.0*p1.y)-(    p0.y);
    q2=vec2(0.0,0.0);
    q3=vec2(0.0,0.0);
    // sample curve by chunks
    for (p1=cubic(0.0),i=0,t=dt;i<n;i++,t+=dt)
        {
        // sample point
        p0=p1; p1=cubic(t); q0=q2; q1=q3;
        // compute ~OBB enlarged by D
        u=normalize(p1-p0);
        v=vec2(u.y,-u.x);
        // resample chunk to compute enlargement
        for (d0=0.0,d1=0.0,tt=t-dtt,j=2;j<m;j++,tt-=dtt)
            {
            dd=dot(cubic(tt)-p0,v);
            d0=max(-dd,d0);
            d1=max(+dd,d1);
            }
        d0+=d; d1+=d; u*=d;
        d0*=1.25; d1*=1.25; // just to be sure
        // enlarge radial
        q2=p1+(v*d1);
        q3=p1-(v*d0);
        // enlarge axial
        if (i==0)
            {
            q0=p0+(v*d1)-u;
            q1=p0-(v*d0)-u;
            }
        if (i==n-1)
            {
            q2+=u;
            q3+=u;
            }
        // pass it as QUAD
        fcol=vcol[0]; trange=vec2(t-dt,t);
        fpos=q0; gl_Position=vec4(q0,0.0,1.0); EmitVertex();
        fpos=q1; gl_Position=vec4(q1,0.0,1.0); EmitVertex();
        fpos=q2; gl_Position=vec4(q2,0.0,1.0); EmitVertex();
        fpos=q3; gl_Position=vec4(q3,0.0,1.0); EmitVertex();
        EndPrimitive();
        }
    }
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------*
```

**Fragment:**

```
// Fragment
#version 400 core

//#define show_coverage

uniform float d=0.05;   // half thickness

in vec2 fpos;           // fragment position
in vec3 fcol;           // fragment color
in vec2 a0,a1,a2,a3;    // cubic coefficients
in vec2 trange;         // t range of chunk

out vec4 col;

vec2 cubic(float t)     // return point on cubic from parameter
    {
    float tt=t*t,ttt=tt*t;
    return a0+(a1*t)+(a2*tt)+(a3*ttt);
    }

void main()
    {
    vec2 p;
    int i,n;
    float t,tt,t0,t1,dt,l,ll;
    tt=-1.0; ll=-1.0; l=0.0;
    #ifdef show_coverage
    t0=0.0; t1=1.0; dt=0.05; n=3;
    #else
    t0=trange.x; n=2;
    t1=trange.y;
    dt=(t1-t0)*0.1;
    #endif
    for (i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
        for (t=t0;t<=t1;t+=dt)
            {
            p=cubic(t)-fpos;
            l=length(p);
            if ((ll<0.0)||(ll>l)){ ll=l; tt=t; }
            }
        t0=tt-dt; if (t0<0.0) t0=0.0;
        t1=tt+dt; if (t1>1.0) t1=1.0;
        dt*=0.2;
        }
    #ifdef show_coverage
    if (ll>d) col=vec4(0.1,0.1,0.1,1.0); else
    #else
    if (ll>d) discard;
    #endif
    col=vec4(fcol,1.0);
    }
```

And preview (curve + coverage):

[image: better coverage]

And just curve:

[image: curve]

as You can see the seam at the crossing wit hcoverage is due to coverage rendering without blending. The curve itself is OK.

The `d0,d1` parameters are the max perpendicular distances to th actual chunk OBB axial axis (u) enlarged by `d` and scaled up by 25% just to be sure. Looks like it fits very good. I doubt there is much to be gained by further optimizations as this result is pretty close to perfect fit of the coverage...

the `#define show_coverage` just enables to view what geometry is passed to fragment shader ...

Comment: This is a bit cumbersome method for me. I need to check if there is another way to solve this as I asked.

Comment: @RyanKane I understand but I am afraid that 2D cubic solver decision tree will be slower than simple few cycles search ... and also the equaitons might lead to problems with floating point precision pretty quick especially in GLSL. I think better would be improving the geometry passed to fragment to be more close to the curve itself as right now is mostly empty space... like emitting triangle strip around the curve sampled from 10 or more triangles ... that should speed up the stuff considerably...

Comment: I understand the calculation of `t` can also be cumbersome. But I hope that part of the calculation can be done only once before and then transferred to the fragment shader. And check pixels only for the rectangle bounding the curve. It all depends on a formula that I have not yet seen to close this question. Now I am looking for a mathematician who can express `t`, and in any case I will post the results of this study here.

Comment: In most cases, the curve will not be long and connect the nodes in the form of a sinusoid curve. I could generally just draw a sine wave with a short formula. But I need bezier curves only because of the special properties of their control points that keep the curve smooth despite the fact that the end point can be moved behind the start point.

Comment: @RyanKane I doubt that you can move the computation from fragment as each change in coordinate changes the equations for roots extraction. If you do precomputation into form of  map/texture then you break the OpenGL pipeline performance and would need another search in fragment so that is why I do not expect its a good idea but math its not my strong suite and I can miss something. See [Interpolation cubic vs. Bezier cubic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22582447/2521214) its a form of Catmull-Rom and the curve is much closer to the control points so BBOX is smaller but need  small enlargement

Comment: @RyanKane "But I hope that part of the calculation can be done only once" how often do the control points change? Even if the calculation is done "once", it might still be faster to do a numerical solution than one which involves square roots.

Comment: Trying to check the formula from the image. It is not very clear how to find Acos (-173.284023). Acos accepts a range of values (-1 to 1). I substitute the valid `x` value point on the curve calculated preliminarily. Other variants with asin the same.Well, this is not surprising =) After all, as it turned out, the expression t is a formula with four unknowns `v0`, `v1`, `v2` and `v3`. x = a.x * v0 + b.x * v1 + c.x * v2 + d.x * v3;

Comment: If we get at least one of v. We can use any part of the formula to invert and get t. But we only have the sum of the elements. Both the value and the ratio of the coefficients v vary among themselves depending on different values ​​of t.

Comment: I have an idea, maybe we can find the value of the coefficients by constructing a formula similar to Cubic Bezier, with a different ratio of the elements between them, then new ways of expressing t will become available. I will try to find patterns by plotting the values of the elements of the equation depending on the value of `t`.

Comment: @RyanKane the formula on my image is final (done with DFW) no need to invert anything ... its just too complicated to compute in GLSL with usable accuracy and performance. The formulas in Stratubas's answer are much better for this as they are using just sqrt and polynomials however they are in complex domain so you need to separate `I` first which is doable but the complexity of the equation is also not good for GLSL. See [ray and ellipsoid intersection accuracy improvement](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25470493/2521214) and that is just quadratics ...

Comment: @RyanKane Btw the coverage of my updated geometry shader might be even further improved by using approximate OBB instead of AABB ... Also not sure if the point is just outside domain (not on the curve) or I had solution checked in [deg] units instead of [rad] in the DFW solver ... I did not test it at all when I saw the horribleness

Comment: What is DFW mean? That's some software name?

Comment: @RyanKane was curious so I implemented it see [edit3] but beware it might not be safe if `D` is not set properly. DFW is Derive for Windows .... I am on Derive from MS-DOS times its a math tool back in the days was even capable of outputing pascal source code for equations ...

Comment: @RyanKane But I have an idea how to speed up the fragment ... by passing `t` range from the geometry shader (after the changes in geometry we know exactly from where to where the `t` goes for emitted primitive ... that can speed up the fragment shader maybe ten fold

Comment: @RyanKane I reedited the `[edit3]` added all 3 shaders will all the improvements (the 10 times speed up of fragment shader included)... estimated speed up of all improvements ~40-100 times counting both better coverage and `t` range passing to fragment. The coverage is safe now no need to tweak anything

Answer (score 4):

See this tricky bezier curve:

[image: tricky bezier curve]

There is no one solution for `t`, there are (up to) 3 solutions.

*(edit1: As stated in Salix alba's answer, it doesn't mean you can't find them. When you thought that there was only one `tx` and one `ty`, you checked if they're (almost) equal. Going to 3 solutions, you could find the `tx`'s and `ty`'s and check if there is an (almost) common real value, but I think it should be sufficient (**and faster**) to check if `bezierY(tx)` is (almost) equal to `glFragCoord.y` for any `tx`, without calculating any `ty`. Also since `tx`'s are the same for every pixel that has the same `x`, see if you can calculate them only once for each unique `x`.*)

I haven't worked with bezier curves much, and never with glsl, so here's an idea that might be bad:

Every time your control points change, do a `t` loop to generate a list of `{x,y}` points, and possibly store them in some kind of unordered map. Then, in your shader, for every pixel, if that pixel exists in that map, apply the desired effect.

You can add nearby points too, and store the distance from the curve as the value in the map, so you can do some kind of anti-aliasing if you want to.

The step size in the `t` loop will have to be small enough, so that no points will be missed, but large enough, so that it will be fast. You can implement a dynamic `t` step, by checking how close the next point is to the previous point. If it's too close, increase the step. If it's too far, decrease the step.

You can also try using a 2d array instead of a map, something like 512x512 booleans. Initialize every element with `false`, and change the values to `true` for the points generated in your `t` loop. Meanwhile, store a list of the array indices that are currently `true`, so you can only initialize the 2d array once, and when your curve changes, flip every `true` back to `false`, empty your list of indices, and repeat the `t` loop etc.

---

(edit2, after your update)

Instead of searching "how to express the variable t from a cubic bezier equation", you can search for a "cubic equation solution" generally. If I'm not mistaken, the bezier equations (of x or y) can be written as

```
(-a + 3b - 3c + d) t^3 + (3a - 6b + 3c) t^2 + (-3a + 3b) t + (a - x) = 0
```

where `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` are the x (or y) components of the control points, and `x` is the x (or y) component of the curve, so they're just cubic equations. See that `x` appears only in the last coefficient, which might make things easier when you need to solve lots of them and their only difference is the value of `x`.

There should be simpler solutions, but if you have access to complex arithmetic *(or are willing to write it yourself using vec2, see [Spektre's answer an "How to compute Discrete Fourier Transform"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26355569/6002078))*, you can try these 3 solutions for `t` I got from Mathematica (`I` is the imaginary unit):

```
(-2*(a - 2*b + c) + (2*2^(1/3)*(b^2 + c^2 + a*(-c + d) - b*(c + d)))/(-2*b^3 + 3*a*b*c + 3*b^2*c - 6*a*c^2 + 3*b*c^2 - 2*c^3 - a^2*d + 3*a*b*d - 6*b^2*d + 3*a*c*d + 3*b*c*d - a*d^2 + a^2*x - 6*a*b*x + 9*b^2*x + 6*a*c*x - 18*b*c*x + 9*c^2*x - 2*a*d*x + 6*b*d*x - 6*c*d*x + d^2*x + Sqrt[(a - 3*b + 3*c - d)^2*(4*b^3*(d - x) + a^2*(d - x)^2 + x*(-4*c^3 + 9*c^2*x - 6*c*d*x + d^2*x) - 3*b^2*(c^2 - 2*c*x + (4*d - 3*x)*x) + 2*a*(2*c^3 - 6*c^2*x + 3*c*x*(d + x) - d*x*(d + x)) + 6*b*(a*(c - x)*(-d + x) + x*(c^2 + c*d - 3*c*x + d*x)))])^(1/3) + 2^(2/3)*(-2*b^3 + 3*a*b*c + 3*b^2*c - 6*a*c^2 + 3*b*c^2 - 2*c^3 - a^2*d + 3*a*b*d - 6*b^2*d + 3*a*c*d + 3*b*c*d - a*d^2 + a^2*x - 6*a*b*x + 9*b^2*x + 6*a*c*x - 18*b*c*x + 9*c^2*x - 2*a*d*x + 6*b*d*x - 6*c*d*x + d^2*x + Sqrt[(a - 3*b + 3*c - d)^2*(4*b^3*(d - x) + a^2*(d - x)^2 + x*(-4*c^3 + 9*c^2*x - 6*c*d*x + d^2*x) - 3*b^2*(c^2 - 2*c*x + (4*d - 3*x)*x) + 2*a*(2*c^3 - 6*c^2*x + 3*c*x*(d + x) - d*x*(d + x)) + 6*b*(a*(c - x)*(-d + x) + x*(c^2 + c*d - 3*c*x + d*x)))])^(1/3))/(2*(-a + 3*b - 3*c + d))
```

```
(-36*(a - 2*b + c) - ((18*I)*2^(1/3)*(-I + Sqrt[3])*(b^2 + c^2 + a*(-c + d) - b*(c + d)))/(-2*b^3 + 3*a*b*c + 3*b^2*c - 6*a*c^2 + 3*b*c^2 - 2*c^3 - a^2*d + 3*a*b*d - 6*b^2*d + 3*a*c*d + 3*b*c*d - a*d^2 + a^2*x - 6*a*b*x + 9*b^2*x + 6*a*c*x - 18*b*c*x + 9*c^2*x - 2*a*d*x + 6*b*d*x - 6*c*d*x + d^2*x + Sqrt[(a - 3*b + 3*c - d)^2*(4*b^3*(d - x) + a^2*(d - x)^2 + x*(-4*c^3 + 9*c^2*x - 6*c*d*x + d^2*x) - 3*b^2*(c^2 - 2*c*x + (4*d - 3*x)*x) + 2*a*(2*c^3 - 6*c^2*x + 3*c*x*(d + x) - d*x*(d + x)) + 6*b*(a*(c - x)*(-d + x) + x*(c^2 + c*d - 3*c*x + d*x)))])^(1/3) + (9*I)*2^(2/3)*(I + Sqrt[3])*(-2*b^3 + 3*a*b*c + 3*b^2*c - 6*a*c^2 + 3*b*c^2 - 2*c^3 - a^2*d + 3*a*b*d - 6*b^2*d + 3*a*c*d + 3*b*c*d - a*d^2 + a^2*x - 6*a*b*x + 9*b^2*x + 6*a*c*x - 18*b*c*x + 9*c^2*x - 2*a*d*x + 6*b*d*x - 6*c*d*x + d^2*x + Sqrt[(a - 3*b + 3*c - d)^2*(4*b^3*(d - x) + a^2*(d - x)^2 + x*(-4*c^3 + 9*c^2*x - 6*c*d*x + d^2*x) - 3*b^2*(c^2 - 2*c*x + (4*d - 3*x)*x) + 2*a*(2*c^3 - 6*c^2*x + 3*c*x*(d + x) - d*x*(d + x)) + 6*b*(a*(c - x)*(-d + x) + x*(c^2 + c*d - 3*c*x + d*x)))])^(1/3))/(36*(-a + 3*b - 3*c + d))
```

```
(-36*(a - 2*b + c) + ((18*I)*2^(1/3)*(I + Sqrt[3])*(b^2 + c^2 + a*(-c + d) - b*(c + d)))/(-2*b^3 + 3*a*b*c + 3*b^2*c - 6*a*c^2 + 3*b*c^2 - 2*c^3 - a^2*d + 3*a*b*d - 6*b^2*d + 3*a*c*d + 3*b*c*d - a*d^2 + a^2*x - 6*a*b*x + 9*b^2*x + 6*a*c*x - 18*b*c*x + 9*c^2*x - 2*a*d*x + 6*b*d*x - 6*c*d*x + d^2*x + Sqrt[(a - 3*b + 3*c - d)^2*(4*b^3*(d - x) + a^2*(d - x)^2 + x*(-4*c^3 + 9*c^2*x - 6*c*d*x + d^2*x) - 3*b^2*(c^2 - 2*c*x + (4*d - 3*x)*x) + 2*a*(2*c^3 - 6*c^2*x + 3*c*x*(d + x) - d*x*(d + x)) + 6*b*(a*(c - x)*(-d + x) + x*(c^2 + c*d - 3*c*x + d*x)))])^(1/3) - 9*2^(2/3)*(1 + I*Sqrt[3])*(-2*b^3 + 3*a*b*c + 3*b^2*c - 6*a*c^2 + 3*b*c^2 - 2*c^3 - a^2*d + 3*a*b*d - 6*b^2*d + 3*a*c*d + 3*b*c*d - a*d^2 + a^2*x - 6*a*b*x + 9*b^2*x + 6*a*c*x - 18*b*c*x + 9*c^2*x - 2*a*d*x + 6*b*d*x - 6*c*d*x + d^2*x + Sqrt[(a - 3*b + 3*c - d)^2*(4*b^3*(d - x) + a^2*(d - x)^2 + x*(-4*c^3 + 9*c^2*x - 6*c*d*x + d^2*x) - 3*b^2*(c^2 - 2*c*x + (4*d - 3*x)*x) + 2*a*(2*c^3 - 6*c^2*x + 3*c*x*(d + x) - d*x*(d + x)) + 6*b*(a*(c - x)*(-d + x) + x*(c^2 + c*d - 3*c*x + d*x)))])^(1/3))/(36*(-a + 3*b - 3*c + d))
```

They are large, but they contain many common sub-expressions (like `(a - 2*b + c)`) which you can evaluate once and reuse, to improve performance (if all this works at all).

For the tricky bezier I posted, here are the 3 solutions:

```
red = (6 + (4*2^(1/3))/(-9 + 49*x + 7*Sqrt[1 + x*(-18 + 49*x)])^(1/3) + 2^(2/3)*(-9 + 49*x + 7*Sqrt[1 + x*(-18 + 49*x)])^(1/3))/14
green = (12 - ((4*I)*2^(1/3)*(-I + Sqrt[3]))/(-9 + 49*x + 7*Sqrt[1 - 18*x + 49*x^2])^(1/3) + I*2^(2/3)*(I + Sqrt[3])*(-9 + 49*x + 7*Sqrt[1 - 18*x + 49*x^2])^(1/3))/28
blue = (12 + ((4*I)*2^(1/3)*(I + Sqrt[3]))/(-9 + 49*x + 7*Sqrt[1 - 18*x + 49*x^2])^(1/3) - 2^(2/3)*(1 + I*Sqrt[3])*(-9 + 49*x + 7*Sqrt[1 - 18*x + 49*x^2])^(1/3))/28
```

[image: t-vs-x for the tricky bezier]

---

(edit3) Following Spektre's suggestion, using the coefficients of a cubic directly

```
x = a*t^3 + b*t^2 + c*t + d
```

(instead of using the control points' coordinates) gives cleaner expressions:

```
1st(red) = (-2*b + (2*2^(1/3)*(b^2 - 3*a*c))/(-2*b^3 + 9*a*b*c - 27*a^2*d + Sqrt[-4*(b^2 - 3*a*c)^3 + (2*b^3 - 9*a*b*c + 27*a^2*(d - x))^2] + 27*a^2*x)^(1/3) + 2^(2/3)*(-2*b^3 + 9*a*b*c - 27*a^2*d + Sqrt[-4*(b^2 - 3*a*c)^3 + (2*b^3 - 9*a*b*c + 27*a^2*(d - x))^2] + 27*a^2*x)^(1/3))/(6*a)
2nd(green) = (-4*b + (2*2^(1/3)*(1 + I*Sqrt[3])*(-b^2 + 3*a*c))/(-2*b^3 + 9*a*b*c - 27*a^2*d + Sqrt[-4*(b^2 - 3*a*c)^3 + (2*b^3 - 9*a*b*c + 27*a^2*(d - x))^2] + 27*a^2*x)^(1/3) + I*2^(2/3)*(I + Sqrt[3])*(-2*b^3 + 9*a*b*c - 27*a^2*d + Sqrt[-4*(b^2 - 3*a*c)^3 + (2*b^3 - 9*a*b*c + 27*a^2*(d - x))^2] + 27*a^2*x)^(1/3))/(12*a)
3rd(blue) = -(4*b - ((2*I)*2^(1/3)*(I + Sqrt[3])*(b^2 - 3*a*c))/(-2*b^3 + 9*a*b*c - 27*a^2*d + Sqrt[-4*(b^2 - 3*a*c)^3 + (2*b^3 - 9*a*b*c + 27*a^2*(d - x))^2] + 27*a^2*x)^(1/3) + 2^(2/3)*(1 + I*Sqrt[3])*(-2*b^3 + 9*a*b*c - 27*a^2*d + Sqrt[-4*(b^2 - 3*a*c)^3 + (2*b^3 - 9*a*b*c + 27*a^2*(d - x))^2] + 27*a^2*x)^(1/3))/(12*a)
```

You can easily transform your control point's coordinates into these coordinates:

```
direct a = control (-a + 3 b - 3 c + d)
direct b = control (3 a - 6 b + 3 c)
direct c = control (-3 a + 3 b)
direct d = control a
```

Comment: Get it. Even if i manage to get a t value. I cant find relations between t for x and t for y. So it will be drawn like rectangle of all possible values. Example of this i haved, when my shader been without that check "if(abs(tx-ty) <  0.01f)". If i manage how to pass byte map in shader that will be good sollution. Question closed.

Comment: I mean: even if i know, "t" for X and "t" for Y, of current pixel coordinate. Even if "t"-values, will be between 0 and 1. Based on your example: I can't know that right point.  Because for one "tX" may be three "tY". And i can't even know what "tY" must be for "tX" to say: so that point definitely lay on curve. So expression of "t" from bezier equation, doesn't make any sense. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Stratubas yes but the result would be horrible mess not to mention from performance aspect not sure how good are GLSL inlines ... And also a lot of work that I have no mood to do as I am too lazy while if you separate the equation in your math tool  into `(.....) + (......)*I` it would be much much simpler.

Answer (score 2):

Bezier curves are basically cubics and there is a formula getting the results of cubics which you can see by looking at [Cubic equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation) on Wikipedia. It is pretty complex but you can follow through the method. Rather than use the formula is easier to follow through the steps of the methods. This Quora question [How can I solve an equation of the third degree?](https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-solve-an-equation-of-the-third-degree) has answers which discuss the various methods in details.

The other answer mentions that the solution is not always unique, for a given value of `x` there may be one, two or three possible values of `t`. As you work through the algorithm there are a couple of times where you need to calculate the square roots of a number, this will have two solutions either +sqrt(...), or -sqrt(...). Following through the algorithm for each value will give you the solutions.

I should also mention that the intermediate part of the algorithm will involve complex numbers whenever the square root of a negative number is calculated. Again you need to consider a pair of solutions which will be complex conjugates.