# Bresenham's Algorithm Anti-aliased quadratic Bézier curve with line thickness

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, bezier, bresenham

In the document found at http://members.chello.at/easyfilter/bresenham.html it walks through the process of creating curves based arround the Bresenham's Algorithm, and it ends with an algorithm to create anti-aliased thick lines, but how can this be aplied to the Quadratic Bezier Curves (the Anti Aliased version found on the same site)?

I tried change the plotQuadBezierSegAA function's last line to use the algorithm of the thick line, but obviously it did not worked as it is computing the other pixels one by one. (I changed from `plotLineAA(x0,y0, x2,y2);` to `plotLineWidth(x0, y0, x2, y2, wd);`)

I also tried to draw more curves slightly shifted until it had the wanted thickness, but it creates problems with the anti aliasing colors. (A for loop that shifted by the x and y step (xx and yy variables) and recursively called the plotQuadBezierSegWidth).

None of this tries actualy worked, so could please someone help me acomplish the thickness in this curves. (The algorithm so far is the one from plotQuadBezierSegAA found on that site).

Code for the shifting:

```cpp
void plotQuadBezierSegAA(int x0, int y0, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, int wd)
{  
   int sx = x2-x1, sy = y2-y1;
   long xx = x0-x1, yy = y0-y1, xy;         /* relative values for checks */
   double dx, dy, err, ed, cur = xx*sy-yy*sx;                /* curvature */

   assert(xx*sx >= 0 && yy*sy >= 0);  /* sign of gradient must not change */

   if (sx*(long)sx+sy*(long)sy > xx*xx+yy*yy) { /* begin with longer part */ 
      x2 = x0; x0 = sx+x1; y2 = y0; y0 = sy+y1; cur = -cur; /* swap P0 P2 */
   }  
   if (cur != 0)
   {                                                  /* no straight line */
      xx += sx; xx *= sx = x0 < x2 ? 1 : -1;          /* x step direction */
      yy += sy; yy *= sy = y0 < y2 ? 1 : -1;          /* y step direction */
      // SHIFTING HERE
      plotQuadBezierSegAA(x0 + xx, y0 + yy, x1 + xx, y1 + yy, x2 + xx, y2 + yy, wd - 1);
      xy = 2*xx*yy; xx *= xx; yy *= yy;         /* differences 2nd degree */
      if (cur*sx*sy < 0) {                          /* negated curvature? */
         xx = -xx; yy = -yy; xy = -xy; cur = -cur;
      }
      dx = 4.0*sy*(x1-x0)*cur+xx-xy;            /* differences 1st degree */
      dy = 4.0*sx*(y0-y1)*cur+yy-xy;
      xx += xx; yy += yy; err = dx+dy+xy;               /* error 1st step */
      do {                              
         cur = fmin(dx+xy,-xy-dy);
         ed = fmax(dx+xy,-xy-dy);           /* approximate error distance */
         ed = 255/(ed+2*ed*cur*cur/(4.*ed*ed+cur*cur)); 
         setPixelAA(x0,y0, ed*fabs(err-dx-dy-xy));          /* plot curve */
         if (x0 == x2 && y0 == y2) return;/* last pixel -> curve finished */
         x1 = x0; cur = dx-err; y1 = 2*err+dy < 0;
         if (2*err+dx > 0) {                                    /* x step */
            if (err-dy < ed) setPixelAA(x0,y0+sy, ed*fabs(err-dy));
            x0 += sx; dx -= xy; err += dy += yy;
         }
         if (y1) {                                              /* y step */
            if (cur < ed) setPixelAA(x1+sx,y0, ed*fabs(cur));
            y0 += sy; dy -= xy; err += dx += xx; 
         }
      } while (dy < dx);              /* gradient negates -> close curves */
   }
   plotLineAA(x0,y0, x2,y2);              /* plot remaining needle to end */
}
```

Comment: Constant thickness is perpendicular to the direction of the line.  A shifted line would look too wide in some parts and too narrow in others.  I think this takes some heavy math.

Comment: Can the radius' for each successive curve can be adjusted smaller or bigger, while ensuring each curve is plotted about the same center?  i.e. for each successive shift of 1 [pixel, mm, inch,...]  the radius of the curve would also change by the same amount.

Comment: Why risk overflow with `long xx = x0-x1`?  1) Change all  `long` to `long long`  2) cast _before_ math  `long long xx = (long long)x0-x1`.

Comment: The "Anti-aliased thick line" section _exclusively_ works for straight lines, because we can guarantee a 1px distance between each successive perpendicular, and so we can use the dx/dy trick without getting gaps across iterations. For _any_ kind of curve, that approach is insufficient, and you're instead going to have more success with drawing the two offset curves and then filling the area between them. And now you have a new problem, because creating offset curves is hard. [Especially for Beziers](https://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/#offsetting)

Comment: see [Is it possible to express "t" variable from Cubic Bezier Curve equation?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60113617/2521214) you can use the fractional part of distance to curve to compute the antialiased color. The link is for cubic curves if you want quadratic then just change the equations.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

In the scratchpad (js file here: http://members.chello.at/easyfilter/bresenham.js lines 909 to 1049) it uses the plotQuadRationalBezierWidth with the w set as 1 to compute a normal Bezier curve with a specified amount of width for the thickness of the line (the wd parameter).

The ported c code from the file:

```cpp
void plotQuadRationalBezierWidthSeg(
    int x0, int y0, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, int w, float th) { /* plot a limited rational Bezier segment
                                        of thickness th, squared weight */
    int sx = x2 - x1, sy = y2 - y1;  /* relative values for checks */
    int dx = x0 - x2, dy = y0 - y2, xx = x0 - x1, yy = y0 - y1;
    double xy = xx * sy + yy * sx, cur = xx * sy - yy * sx, err, e2,
        ed; /* curvature */
    bool fullBreak = false;

    if (cur != 0.0 && w > 0.0) { /* no straight line */
        if (sx * sx + sy * sy >
            xx * xx + yy * yy) { /* begin with longer part */
            x2 = x0;
            x0 -= dx;
            y2 = y0;
            y0 -= dy;
            cur = -cur; /* swap P0 P2 */
        }
        xx = 2.0 * (4.0 * w * sx * xx + dx * dx); /* differences 2nd degree */
        yy = 2.0 * (4.0 * w * sy * yy + dy * dy);
        sx = x0 < x2 ? 1 : -1; /* x step direction */
        sy = y0 < y2 ? 1 : -1; /* y step direction */
        xy = -2.0 * sx * sy * (2.0 * w * xy + dx * dy);

        if (cur * sx * sy < 0) { /* negated curvature? */
            xx = -xx;
            yy = -yy;
            cur = -cur;
            xy = -xy;
        }
        dx = 4.0 * w * (x1 - x0) * sy * cur +
             xx / 2.0; /* differences 1st degree */
        dy = 4.0 * w * (y0 - y1) * sx * cur + yy / 2.0;

        if (w < 0.5 &&
            (dx + xx <= 0 || dy + yy >= 0)) { /* flat ellipse, algo fails */
            cur = (w + 1.0) / 2.0;
            w = std::sqrtf(w);
            xy = 1.0 / (w + 1.0);
            sx = std::floor((x0 + 2.0 * w * x1 + x2) * xy / 2.0 +
                            0.5); /* subdivide curve  */
            sy = std::floor((y0 + 2.0 * w * y1 + y2) * xy / 2.0 +
                            0.5); /* plot separately */
            dx = std::floor((w * x1 + x0) * xy + 0.5);
            dy = std::floor((y1 * w + y0) * xy + 0.5);
            plotQuadRationalBezierWidthSeg(x0, y0, dx, dy, sx, sy, cur, th);
            dx = std::floor((w * x1 + x2) * xy + 0.5);
            dy = std::floor((y1 * w + y2) * xy + 0.5);
            return plotQuadRationalBezierWidthSeg(sx, sy, dx, dy, x2, y2, cur,
                                                  th);
        }
        
        for (err = 0;
             dy + 2 * yy < 0 && dx + 2 * xx > 0;) /* loop of steep/flat curve */
            if (dx + dy + xy < 0) {               /* steep curve */
                do {
                    ed = -dy -
                         2 * dy * dx * dx /
                             (4. * dy * dy + dx * dx); /* approximate sqrt */
                    w = (th - 1) * ed;                 /* scale line width */
                    x1 = std::floor((err - ed - w / 2) / dy); /* start offset */
                    e2 = err - x1 * dy - w / 2; /* error value at offset */
                    x1 = x0 - x1 * sx;          /* start point */
                    setPixel(x1, y0, 255 * e2 / ed); /* aliasing pre-pixel */
                    for (e2 = -w - dy - e2; e2 - dy < ed; e2 -= dy)
                        setPixel(x1 += sx, y0); /* pixel on thick line */
                    setPixel(x1 + sx, y0,
                               255 * e2 / ed); /* aliasing post-pixel */
                    if (y0 == y2) return; /* last pixel -> curve finished */
                    y0 += sy;
                    dy += xy;
                    err += dx;
                    dx += xx;               /* y step */
                    if (2 * err + dy > 0) { /* e_x+e_xy > 0 */
                        x0 += sx;
                        dx += xy;
                        err += dy;
                        dy += yy; /* x step */
                    }
                    if (x0 != x2 && (dx + 2 * xx <= 0 || dy + 2 * yy >= 0))
                        if (std::abs(y2 - y0) > std::abs(x2 - x0)) {
                            fullBreak = true;
                            break;
                        } else
                            break;          /* other curve near */
                } while (dx + dy + xy < 0); /* gradient still steep? */

                if (fullBreak) break;

                /* change from steep to flat curve */
                for (cur = err - dy - w / 2, y1 = y0; cur < ed;
                     y1 += sy, cur += dx) {
                    for (e2 = cur, x1 = x0; e2 - dy < ed; e2 -= dy)
                        setPixel(x1 -= sx, y1); /* pixel on thick line */
                    setPixel(x1 - sx, y1,
                               255 * e2 / ed); /* aliasing post-pixel */
                }
            } else { /* flat curve */
                do {
                    ed = dx +
                         2 * dx * dy * dy /
                             (4. * dx * dx + dy * dy); /* approximate sqrt */
                    w = (th - 1) * ed;                 /* scale line width */
                    y1 = std::floor((err + ed + w / 2) / dx); /* start offset */
                    e2 = y1 * dx - w / 2 - err; /* error value at offset */
                    y1 = y0 - y1 * sy;          /* start point */
                    setPixel(x0, y1, 255 * e2 / ed); /* aliasing pre-pixel */
                    for (e2 = dx - e2 - w; e2 + dx < ed; e2 += dx)
                        setPixel(x0, y1 += sy); /* pixel on thick line */
                    setPixel(x0, y1 + sy,
                               255 * e2 / ed); /* aliasing post-pixel */
                    if (x0 == x2) return; /* last pixel -> curve finished */
                    x0 += sx;
                    dx += xy;
                    err += dy;
                    dy += yy;               /* x step */
                    if (2 * err + dx < 0) { /* e_y+e_xy < 0 */
                        y0 += sy;
                        dy += xy;
                        err += dx;
                        dx += xx; /* y step */
                    }
                    if (y0 != y2 && (dx + 2 * xx <= 0 || dy + 2 * yy >= 0))
                        if (std::abs(y2 - y0) <= std::abs(x2 - x0)) {
                            fullBreak = true;
                            break;
                        } else
                            break;           /* other curve near */
                } while (dx + dy + xy >= 0); /* gradient still flat? */

                if (fullBreak) break;

                /* change from flat to steep curve */
                for (cur = -err + dx - w / 2, x1 = x0; cur < ed;
                     x1 += sx, cur -= dy) {
                    for (e2 = cur, y1 = y0; e2 + dx < ed; e2 += dx)
                        setPixel(x1, y1 -= sy); /* pixel on thick line */
                    setPixel(x1, y1 - sy,
                               255 * e2 / ed); /* aliasing post-pixel */
                }
            }
    }
    setLine(x0, y0, x2, y2, th); /* confusing error values  */
}

void plotQuadRationalBezierWidth(
    int x0, int y0, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, int w,
    float th) { /* plot any anti-aliased quadratic rational Bezier curve */
    int x = x0 - 2 * x1 + x2, y = y0 - 2 * y1 + y2;
    double xx = x0 - x1, yy = y0 - y1, ww, t, q;

    if (xx * (x2 - x1) > 0) {   /* horizontal cut at P4? */
        if (yy * (y2 - y1) > 0) /* vertical cut at P6 too? */
            if (std::abs(xx * y) > std::abs(yy * x)) { /* which first? */
                x0 = x2;
                x2 = xx + x1;
                y0 = y2;
                y2 = yy + y1; /* swap points */
            }                 /* now horizontal cut at P4 comes first */
        if (x0 == x2 || w == 1.0)
            t = (x0 - x1) / x;
        else { /* non-rational or rational case */
            q = std::sqrt(4.0 * w * w * (x0 - x1) * (x2 - x1) +
                          (x2 - x0) * (x2 - x0));
            if (x1 < x0) q = -q;
            t = (2.0 * w * (x0 - x1) - x0 + x2 + q) /
                (2.0 * (1.0 - w) * (x2 - x0)); /* t at P4 */
        }
        q = 1.0 / (2.0 * t * (1.0 - t) * (w - 1.0) + 1.0); /* sub-divide at t */
        xx = (t * t * (x0 - 2.0 * w * x1 + x2) + 2.0 * t * (w * x1 - x0) + x0) *
             q; /* = P4 */
        yy = (t * t * (y0 - 2.0 * w * y1 + y2) + 2.0 * t * (w * y1 - y0) + y0) *
             q;
        ww = t * (w - 1.0) + 1.0;
        ww *= ww * q; /* squared weight P3 */
        w = ((1.0 - t) * (w - 1.0) + 1.0) * std::sqrt(q); /* weight P8 */
        x = std::floor(xx + 0.5);
        y = std::floor(yy + 0.5);                    /* P4 */
        yy = (xx - x0) * (y1 - y0) / (x1 - x0) + y0; /* intersect P3 | P0 P1 */
        plotQuadRationalBezierWidthSeg(x0, y0, x, std::floor(yy + 0.5), x, y,
                                       ww, th);
        yy = (xx - x2) * (y1 - y2) / (x1 - x2) + y2; /* intersect P4 | P1 P2 */
        y1 = std::floor(yy + 0.5);
        x0 = x1 = x;
        y0 = y; /* P0 = P4, P1 = P8 */
    }
    if ((y0 - y1) * (y2 - y1) > 0) { /* vertical cut at P6? */
        if (y0 == y2 || w == 1.0)
            t = (y0 - y1) / (y0 - 2.0 * y1 + y2);
        else { /* non-rational or rational case */
            q = std::sqrt(4.0 * w * w * (y0 - y1) * (y2 - y1) +
                          (y2 - y0) * (y2 - y0));
            if (y1 < y0) q = -q;
            t = (2.0 * w * (y0 - y1) - y0 + y2 + q) /
                (2.0 * (1.0 - w) * (y2 - y0)); /* t at P6 */
        }
        q = 1.0 / (2.0 * t * (1.0 - t) * (w - 1.0) + 1.0); /* sub-divide at t */
        xx = (t * t * (x0 - 2.0 * w * x1 + x2) + 2.0 * t * (w * x1 - x0) + x0) *
             q; /* = P6 */
        yy = (t * t * (y0 - 2.0 * w * y1 + y2) + 2.0 * t * (w * y1 - y0) + y0) *
             q;
        ww = t * (w - 1.0) + 1.0;
        ww *= ww * q; /* squared weight P5 */
        w = ((1.0 - t) * (w - 1.0) + 1.0) * std::sqrt(q); /* weight P7 */
        x = std::floor(xx + 0.5);
        y = std::floor(yy + 0.5);                    /* P6 */
        xx = (x1 - x0) * (yy - y0) / (y1 - y0) + x0; /* intersect P6 | P0 P1 */
        plotQuadRationalBezierWidthSeg(x0, y0, std::floor(xx + 0.5), y, x, y,
                                       ww, th);
        xx = (x1 - x2) * (yy - y2) / (y1 - y2) + x2; /* intersect P7 | P1 P2 */
        x1 = std::floor(xx + 0.5);
        x0 = x;
        y0 = y1 = y; /* P0 = P6, P1 = P7 */
    }
    plotQuadRationalBezierWidthSeg(x0, y0, x1, y1, x2, y2, w * w, th);
}

void plotQuadBezierWidth(int x0, int y0, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, int wd) {
    plotQuadRationalBezierWidth(x0, y0, x1, y1, x2, y2, 1, wd);
}
```

Example (Thickness 5px):

```cpp
plotQuadBezierWidth(10, 10, 10, 300, 100, 500, 5);
```

[image: Bezier Curve 5px Stroke]

Example (Thickness 1px):

```cpp
plotQuadBezierWidth(10, 10, 10, 300, 100, 500, 1);
```

[image: Bezier Curve 1px Stroke]

Comment: Is this really an answer to the problem or just more question information?

Comment: This is very much not an answer. Please edit your post to just add this at the end (without an "edit" heading: it's just more information, not a redefinition of your question), and then delete this answer post.

Comment: This kinda of is the answer, as within those lines there is an implementation of a Bézier curve that actually can have a variable thickness, it is in JavaScript but it’s very portable.

Comment: @RuiPedro: Add enough information here to show that it is the answer, perhaps example output with a line thickness greater than 1, compared to a width of 1, and also zoomed in to show that anti-aliasing has taken place.  Together with the parameters passed to that function.