# Determine the next point on the Bézier curve based on the straight-line distance from the previous point

Tags: algorithm, math, distance, bezier, curve

I need to keep the same distance between the balls on the Bézier curve. Now I'm using a simple iteration of possible positions on the curve, adding some step amount for each iteration until position with required distance, greater or equal, is found.
It works, but can be resource-intensive when there are a large amount of balls. ***[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/bezier-with-balls-mz37y?file=/src/index.js)***

```js
class TestScene extends Phaser.Scene {
  create() {
    // prettier-ignore
    const curve = new Phaser.Curves.QuadraticBezier(
      [
        55, 310,
        40, 0,
        250, 310
      ]
    );

    const graphicsLayer = this.add.graphics({
      lineStyle: {
        width: 2,
        color: 0x0000ff
      }
    });

    curve.draw(graphicsLayer);

    const balls = this.initBalls(6);

    this.curve = curve;
    this.balls = balls;
  }

  initBalls(quantity) {
    const balls = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < quantity; i++) {
      const ball = this.add.circle(0, 0, 12, 0x00ff00);
      ball.t = 0;

      balls.push(ball);
    }

    return balls;
  }

  calcNextBallT(previous) {
    const ballDiameter = previous.radius * 2;
    const curve = this.curve;
    const curveLen = curve.getLength();
    const previousPos = new Phaser.Math.Vector2(previous);
    const previousT = previous.t;

    const startingT = (1 / curveLen) * ballDiameter + previousT;

    const step = 1 / 1000;

    let nextT = startingT;
    let nextPos;
    let currentDistance = 0;
    while (nextT >= 0 && nextT <= 1) {
      nextPos = curve.getPointAt(nextT);
      currentDistance = previousPos.distance(nextPos);
      if (currentDistance >= ballDiameter) {
        break;
      }
      nextT += step;
    }

    return nextT;
  }

  update() {
    const {
      curve,
      balls
    } = this;
    if (!curve || !balls) {
      return;
    }

    const speed = 1;
    const curveLen = curve.getLength();
    const step = (1 / curveLen) * speed;

    balls.forEach((ball, index, array) => {
      let nextT = ball.t;

      if (index === 0) {
        nextT += step;
        if (nextT > 1) {
          nextT = 0;
        }
      } else {
        const previous = array[index - 1];
        nextT = this.calcNextBallT(previous);
      }

      ball.t = nextT;
      ball.copyPosition(curve.getPointAt(nextT));
    });
  }
}

const game = new Phaser.Game({
  width: 320,
  height: 320,
  powerPreference: 'low-power',
  audio: {
    noAudio: true
  },
  scene: [TestScene]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/phaser@3.55.2/dist/phaser.min.js"></script>
```

I think maybe there is a mathematical or algorithmic solution. Something like finding the intersection of a larger circle with a curve, but as I understood it is impossible.

Is there a better way to determine the next point on the Bézier curve based on the straight-line distance from the previous point?

**UPDATE 1:** A solution using Binary Search, as suggested by @MBo, shows good stability with an average of 5-10 iterations, even with varying curves and ball sizes. ***[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/bezier-with-balls-binary-search-s4foq?file=/src/index.js)***

```js
class TestScene extends Phaser.Scene {
  init() {
    this.input.on('drag', (pointer, gameObject, dragX, dragY) => {
      gameObject.setPosition(dragX, dragY);
    });

    this.iters = [];
  }

  create() {
    // prettier-ignore
    const p0 = this.add.circle(55, 310, 4, 0xffff00),
          p1 = this.add.circle(40, 5, 4, 0xffff00),
          p2 = this.add.circle(250, 310, 4, 0xffff00);

    const curve = new Phaser.Curves.QuadraticBezier(p0, p1, p2);

    const graphicsLayer = this.add.graphics({
      lineStyle: {
        width: 2,
        color: 0x0000ff
      }
    });
    curve.draw(graphicsLayer);

    const curveDragHandler = () => {
      curve.updateArcLengths();
      graphicsLayer.clear();
      curve.draw(graphicsLayer);
    };

    [p0, p1, p2].forEach((p) => {
      p.setDepth(10).setInteractive();
      this.input.setDraggable(p);
      p.on('drag', curveDragHandler);
    });

    const balls = this.initBalls(3, 50);

    const text = this.add.text(0, 0, '', {
      color: 'yellow'
    });

    this.curve = curve;
    this.balls = balls;
    this.text = text;
  }

  initBalls(quantity, diameter) {
    const radius = diameter / 2;
    const balls = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < quantity; i++) {
      const ball = this.add.circle(0, 0, radius, 0x00ff00);
      ball.t = 0;

      balls.push(ball);
    }

    return balls;
  }

  calcNextBallT(previous) {
    const ballDiameter = previous.radius * 2;
    const curve = this.curve;
    const previousPos = new Phaser.Math.Vector2(previous);
    const previousT = previous.t;

    let nextT = 1;
    let lowT = previousT;
    let highT = 1;
    let iter = 1;
    const skip = previousPos.distance(curve.getEndPoint()) <= ballDiameter;
    while (lowT <= highT && !skip) {
      nextT = lowT + (highT - lowT) / 2;
      const nextPos = curve.getPointAt(nextT);
      const currentDistance = previousPos.distance(nextPos);

      if (fuzzySame(currentDistance, ballDiameter)) {
        break;
      }

      if (currentDistance > ballDiameter) {
        highT = nextT;
      } else {
        lowT = nextT;
      }

      iter++;
    }

    if (!skip) {
      this.iters.push(iter);
    }

    return nextT;
  }

  update() {
    const {
      curve,
      balls
    } = this;
    if (!curve || !balls) {
      return;
    }

    const speed = 1;
    const curveLen = curve.getLength();
    const step = (1 / curveLen) * speed;

    balls.forEach((ball, index, array) => {
      let nextT = ball.t;

      if (index === 0) {
        nextT += step;
        if (nextT > 1) {
          const average = findAverage(this.iters).toFixed(2);
          const maximum = findMaximum(this.iters);
          this.text.setText(`Average: ${average}\nMaximum: ${maximum}`);
          this.iters = [];
          nextT = 0;
        }
      } else {
        const previous = array[index - 1];
        nextT = this.calcNextBallT(previous);
      }

      ball.t = nextT;
      ball.copyPosition(curve.getPointAt(nextT));
    });
  }
}

const fuzzySame = (num1, num2) => {
  const tolerance = 0.2;
  return num1 >= num2 - tolerance && num1 <= num2 + tolerance;
};

const findAverage = (array) => {
  const len = array.length;
  let total = 0;
  array.forEach((num) => (total += num));
  return total / len;
};

const findMaximum = (array) => {
  return [...array].sort((a, b) => b - a)[0];
};

const game = new Phaser.Game({
  width: 320,
  height: 320,
  powerPreference: 'low-power',
  audio: {
    noAudio: true
  },
  scene: [TestScene]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/phaser@3.55.2/dist/phaser.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of straight iterations use binary search over t range.

Math solution requires solving equation of 6-th degree (for cubic curve) - there is no closed formula, so one needs to use numerical methods (iterations again)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but sorry for my incompetence, what do you mean by binary search over t range, normal binary search until the correct position is found?

Comment: Yes, normal binary search. I meant that you know range of t like `current_t .. 1.0`

Comment: Some links to pages that explain this in more detail would be helpful here. e.g. https://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/#tracing but if you know of a better one, by all means edit that into the post. Right now the answer states facts but doesn't really offer visitors with this problem a path forward.

Comment: @EgorTyurin see [Is it possible to express "t" variable from Cubic Bezier Curve equation?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60113617/2521214) it uses different type of search (because binary search is unusable for that, but logic is similar) to find closest point on cubic curve to known position in order to compute distance to curve your task is similar you just search `t` (binary search is OK for that) until found position is eqi distant to what you need ... however you would still need to compute the curve length iteratively first ...