# How do I align the raytraced spheres from my fragment shader with GL_POINTS?

Tags: opengl, glsl, raytracing

I have a very simple shader program that takes in a bunch of position data as GL_POINTS that generate screen-aligned squares of fragments like normal with a size depending on depth, and then in the fragment shader I wanted to draw a very simple ray-traced sphere for each one with just the shadow that is on the sphere opposite to the light. I went to this [shadertoy](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/4d2XWV) to try to figure it out on my own. I used the sphIntersect function for ray-sphere intersection, and sphNormal to get the normal vectors on the sphere for lighting. The problem is that the spheres do not align with the squares of fragments, causing them to be cut off. This is because I am not sure how to match the projections of the spheres and the vertex positions so that they line up. Can I have an explanation of how to do this?

Here is a picture for reference.
[image: i]

Here are my vertex and fragment shaders for reference:

```
//vertex shader:
#version 460

layout(location = 0) in vec4 position; // position of each point in space
layout(location = 1) in vec4 color; //color of each point in space
layout(location = 2) uniform mat4 view_matrix; // projection * camera matrix
layout(location = 6) uniform mat4 cam_matrix; //just the camera matrix
out vec4 col; // color of vertex
out vec4 posi; // position of vertex

void main() {
    vec4 p = view_matrix * vec4(position.xyz, 1.0);
    gl_PointSize = clamp(1024.0 * position.w / p.z, 0.0, 4000.0);
    gl_Position = p;
    col = color;
    posi = cam_matrix * position;
}

//fragment shader:
#version 460

in vec4 col; // color of vertex associated with this fragment
in vec4 posi; // position of the vertex associated with this fragment relative to camera

out vec4 f_color;

layout (depth_less) out float gl_FragDepth;

float sphIntersect( in vec3 ro, in vec3 rd, in vec4 sph )
{
    vec3 oc = ro - sph.xyz;
    float b = dot( oc, rd );
    float c = dot( oc, oc ) - sph.w*sph.w;
    float h = b*b - c;
    if( h<0.0 ) return -1.0;
    return -b - sqrt( h );
}

vec3 sphNormal( in vec3 pos, in vec4 sph )
{
    return normalize(pos-sph.xyz);
}

void main() {

    vec4 c = clamp(col, 0.0, 1.0);
    vec2 p = ((2.0*gl_FragCoord.xy)-vec2(1920.0, 1080.0)) / 2.0;
    
    vec3 ro = vec3(0.0, 0.0, -960.0 );
    vec3 rd = normalize(vec3(p.x, p.y,960.0));
    
    vec3 lig = normalize(vec3(0.6,0.3,0.1));

    vec4 k = vec4(posi.x, posi.y, -posi.z, 2.0*posi.w);

    float t = sphIntersect(ro, rd, k);
    vec3 ps = ro + (t * rd);
    vec3 nor = sphNormal(ps, k);
    
    if(t < 0.0) c = vec4(1.0);
    
    else c.xyz *= clamp(dot(nor,lig), 0.0, 1.0);

    f_color = c;

    gl_FragDepth = t * 0.0001;

}
```

Comment: see [Reflection and refraction impossible without recursive ray tracing?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45140313/2521214) and [Ray and ellipsoid intersection accuracy improvement](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25470493/2521214) and [Atmospheric scattering GLSL fragment shader](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19659648/2521214) the last one is very similar to your problem (it renders atmosphere using QUAD BBOX around ellipsoid ...)

Comment: I will check those out. Also, just to be clear I don't want any crazy effects like reflection or anything like that. I only want one pass just to get shape.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a ray direction that matches a perspective matrix from screen space, the following ray direction formula can be used:

```
vec3 rd = normalize(vec3(((2.0 / screenWidth) * gl_FragCoord.xy) - vec2(aspectRatio, 1.0), -proj_matrix[1][1]));
```

The value of `2.0 / screenWidth` can be pre-computed or the opengl built-in uniform structs can be used.

To get a bounding box or other shape for your spheres, it is very important to use camera-facing shapes, and not camera-plane-facing shapes. Use the following process where `position` is the incoming VBO position data, and the w-component of `position` is the radius:

```
vec4 p = vec4((cam_matrix * vec4(position.xyz, 1.0)).xyz, position.w);
o.vpos = p;

float l2 = dot(p.xyz, p.xyz);
float r2 = p.w * p.w;
float k = 1.0 - (r2/l2);
float radius = p.w * sqrt(k);
if(l2 < r2) {
    p = vec4(0.0, 0.0, -p.w * 0.49, p.w);
    radius = p.w;
    k = 0.0;
}
vec3 hx = radius * normalize(vec3(-p.z, 0.0, p.x));
vec3 hy = radius * normalize(vec3(-p.x * p.y, p.z * p.z + p.x * p.x, -p.z * p.y));
p.xyz *= k;
```

Then use `hx` and `hy` as basis vectors for any 2D shape that you want the billboard to be shaped like for the vertices. Don't forget later to multiply each vertex by a perspective matrix to get the final position of each vertex. Here is a visualization of the billboarding on desmos using a hexagon shape: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/yeeew6tqwx

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have many spheres so I would do this:

1. **Input data**

   I would have VBO containing `x,y,z,r` describing your spheres, You will also need your view transform (uniform) that can create ray direction and start position for each fragment. Something like my vertex shader in here:

   - [Reflection and refraction impossible without recursive ray tracing?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45140313/2521214)
2. **Create BBOX in Geometry shader and convert your POINT to QUAD or POLYGON**

   note that you have to account for perspective. If you are not familiar with geometry shaders see:

   - [rendring cubics in GLSL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60113617/2521214)

   Where I emmit sequence of OBB from input lines...
3. **In fragment raytrace sphere**

   You have to compute [intersection between sphere and ray](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25470493/2521214), chose the closer intersection and compute its depth and normal (for lighting). In case of no intersection you have to `discard;` fragment !!!

From what I can see in your images Your QUADs does not correspond to your spheres hence the clipping and also you do not `discard;` fragments with no intersections so you overwrite with background color already rendered stuff around last rendered spheres so you have only single sphere left in QUAD regardless of how many spheres are really there ...

Comment: I already had my position as x, y, z, r hence why its vec4, and I omit w when I view transform. Also, the reason I didn't discard in the gif was to clearly indicate where the boundaries of the squares were because otherwise since the projections don't line up the spheres are invisible and I would be moving the camera around blindly in order to find them. Also, is it really nessesary to create a BBOX? How much of a performance impact would that have vs making the squares bigger so that the spheres don't clip until they are off screen? I honestly just wanted the projections to line up.

Comment: Then I guess the real question is: If I have a projection matrix and radius how can I... 1) create bboxes that are the correct size? And 2) Define rays that create the same projection as the projection matrix?

Comment: @PlatinumFrog with MVP its tricky... its better to have access to VIEW and MESH matrixes in separate as you need to extract camera axises in order to create valid BBOX ... so you just create square (or what ever) in mesh local coordinates around center of spehere in plane parallel with camera projection plane... this is easily done in Geometry shader... that you can transform with your MVP ... there is almost no performance hit for this ... the real hit can be only geometry shader usage on older HW (not the code inside it)  however modern GL drivers and gfx cards should be fine.