# How to determine t value of original cubic bezier curve after subdivide such curve twice with each t = 0.5?

Tags: math, cubic-bezier

Take [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T0bbT.png) as initial cubic bezier, first subdivide with t=0.5 get point K, then I want to further subdivide the second half cubic bezier KJGD, get a point, let's say M.

[image]

My question is: If I subdivide the original cubic bezier ABCD at the point of M, what is the t value? is it 0.5 + 0.5 * 0.5 = 0.75? (first t=0.5 plus half (0.5) of the second part (0.5))

I use c++ as programming language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `S0` is your original split point *(0.5 in your case)*, and `S1` is the split on the second curve *(again, 0.5 in your case)*, then yes, your split point on the original curve is:

`S0+(1-S0)*S1`,

`0.5+(1-0.5)*0.5 == 0.75`.

Comment: works! seemingly it is linear though I did not dig into it.

Comment: The 't' parameter is linear - however the positions the curve outputs are not.

Answer (score 0):

This is not subdividing the curve but its [recursive De_Casteljau algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Casteljau%27s_algorithm) to compute the value (point on BEZIER) from `t` so the value of `t` is never changing if you used `t=0.5`  it stays the same all the way ...

If you want to obtain `t` of closest point on BEZIER to some point `M` then you need a reverse process see:

- [Is it possible to express "t" variable from Cubic Bezier Curve equation?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60113617/2521214)